# How to suppres INFO spark logs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-3.0

I am experimenting with apache spark 3 in intellij by creating a simple standalone scala application. When I run my program I get lots of INFO logs. Based on various SO answers I tried all of the following:

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR)
Logger.getLogger(classOf[RackResolver]).getLevel
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

But none works. I still see tons of INFO logs.

So what's the working way of achieving this?

Comment: spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR") worked for me.